# List<string> to Alertcontroller

Tags: mysql, string, xamarin.ios, system

Noob question....i am new into developing apps, i hope this question isn't too stupid.

I have a TableView with companys from my database. When I Swipe, I want to have 3 options.

**1.** Show Information about the selected Company in an AlertController
 **2.** Manage some Information about the selected Company
 **3.** Delete the selected Company

My Question is for **Case 1**.

The swipe function works and the AlertController appears. But I have the following error message for the Information from my database:
**`System.Collection.Generic.List'1[Systen.String]`**

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOl9L.jpg)

If you need the hole Code, I can upload it. I hope these two parts are enough.

My code:

```
public partial class ListViewController : UITableViewController
{
    public ListViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    List<string> words = new List<string>();
    List<string> adresse = new List<string>();

  ..... 

 public UIContextualAction ContextualFlagAction(int row)
    {
        var action = UIContextualAction.FromContextualActionStyle(UIContextualActionStyle.Normal,
                                                                  "Flag",
                                                                  (FlagAction, view, success) => {
            var alertController = UIAlertController.Create($"Information über {words[row]}", $"Straße: {adresse}", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

                                                                       //kuddelmuddel beginnt


                                                                      using (MySqlConnection connection2 = new MySqlConnection("Connection String"))
                                                                      {
                                                                            string query = $"SELECT Strasse FROM Kunden WHERE Firma LIKE '{words[row]}'";
                                                                            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection2);                                                          

                                                                          connection2.Open();

                                                                            using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                                                                            {
                                                                            while (reader.Read())
                                                                            {
                                                                            adresse.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                                                                            }  

                                                                          }
                                                                      }


                                                                        //kuddelmuddel endet
                                                                      alertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, null));

                                                                     PresentViewController(alertController, true, null);

                                                                     success(true);
                                                                  });

        action.Image = UIImage.FromFile("feedback.png");
        action.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;

        return action;
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting a compile time error, or a runtime exception?  Which line is causing it?  What is the specific message?  What you posted isn't an actual error message.

Comment: Hey Jason, yes my fault. The app doesn't crash. When i click the button for the information, the AlertController opens. And the "System.Collection.Generic.List'1[Systen.String]" Message is as text in my AlertController. But there should be the entry from my adresse-list

Comment: adresse is a List<string>, but AlertController expects a single string as a parameter.  You need to specify which element of the List to use in the AlertController.

Comment: also, you're building AlertController BEFORE you've populated adresse with data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jason said, the error comes with treating the list as a string.And make the alert show after the db operation.

#### Modify

```
using (MySqlConnection connection2 = new MySqlConnection("Connection String"))
{
    string query = $"SELECT Strasse FROM Kunden WHERE Firma LIKE '{words[row]}'";
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection2);                                                          
    connection2.Open();
    using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
           adresse.Add(reader.GetString(0));
        }  
    }
}

var alertController = UIAlertController.Create($"Information über {words[row]}", $"Straße: {adresse[0]}", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
alertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, null));
PresentViewController(alertController, true, null);
```

Comment: First, thank you. But when i do this, the App Crash. System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException - Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less then the size of the collection. Parameter Name:index

Is it because row is defined for the list words? 

Sorry, i try my best!

Comment: @StefanSuche  the index beyond the array count , put the code above after  the db operation . Check my update.

Comment: THANK YOU. This Works! Super fast Support